# Running a .NET 2.0 app windows form app on Windows 7 with Aero enabled causes menu interactions to crash the application

Tags: .net, windows-7, aero, aero-glass

I have a legacy .NET 2.0 windows forms application that I am working with. It works fine in XP but in Windows 7, if an aero theme is enabled the app starts up, but crashes when you click 'File' in the menu bar. The application runs fine when using a windows basic theme. It also runs fine if I select the 'Disable Desktop Composition' item in the properties of the shortcut.

I have run the code in visual studio with all exceptions turned on and found nothing. The regular windows event logs are no help either.

Comment: What do you mean by "menu bar?"  If it's a console app, then there shouldn't be any menu bar.

Comment: Sorry ! Not a console app but a windows forms application. I shall correct it.

Comment: Are there any event handlers associated with the menu bar or File menu?  You should post that code if there are some.

Comment: .NET is rather excellent at giving you very informative exceptions with a stack trace to show you what went wrong.  If you haven't implemented an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString() then it is high time you do.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the crash? Seeing it might help figure out what *kind* of crash it was.

Comment: There isn't an exception thrown, the application just freezes. It doesn't look like much, the file menu drops down and the app is unresponsive past that. It seems like it takes some time to render the borders of menu dropdown and then freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following items an give it  another try:

1. Check for 32 or 64 bit OS, both in IDE and your OS.
2. Keep the `.config` file with the `.exe` file
3. try to repair .net 2

Comment: Ian, thanks for the info. This happens on multiple 32 bit machines so i dont think its a .net issue with a particular machine. What should I put in the .congif with the exe?